# How do I know what verb form to use with "have", as in "we will soon have your car going" and "it's nice to have people smile"?

Tags: tense, verbs

How can I know when to use **-ing** or **-ed** or **infinitive without to**?

> We will soon have your car "**going**". (Why use "going"?)
>
> It's nice to have people "**smile**" at you in the street (why use "smile"?)

Comment: Related questions: "[Non-finite clause complementation of complex transitive verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114365/non-finite-clause-complementation-of-complex-transitive-verbs)" and [to show (object) do something — grammatical construction](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47766/to-show-object-do-something-grammatical-construction)

Comment: Another good related question: "[use of infinitives after causative verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95031/usage-of-infinitives-in-this-sentence)"

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/32803/3281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your sentence with **smile**, I'll quote from one [PDF by Marcus Callies](http://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/mcallies/talks/SEU.Symposium2009.pdf) that quotes Biber and Huddleston&Pullum:

> verbs taking the bare inf. come from just two semantic classes:
>   (according to Biber:)
>   • perception verbs (*feel, hear (tell), see, watch*);
>   • verbs of modality or causation (*dare, have, help, let, make*)
>   ...
>   (according to Huddleston&Pullum:)
>   sensory perception verbs (*feel, hear, notice, observe, overhear, see, watch*)
>   • *have, let and make* among the causatives
>   • a few are found either with or without to: *ought, dare, know and find*
>   (typical of BrE), *help*

In your second sentence, **have** is a verb of causation: you do something that causes people to smile at you. You can use either **smile** or **smiling**, with **have** but not with **make**, [for example](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv214.shtml).

---

Concerning the **car going**, I guess we can use **go** but the meaning will change to "we will launch your car" or "we will make your car go away".

---

You cannot use the **-ed** form in either of your sentences, it would be ungrammatical

> We will soon have your car **went**. (WRONG)
>   It's nice to have people **smiled** at you in the street. (WRONG)

I'm not 100% sure why, but it's probably because **smiled** and **went** are [finite verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_verb), and in some constructions you are only allowed to use [non-finite verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonfinite_verb). It's probably a "[catenative construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb)" in your case: one verb connects to another verb.

---

Reference:

- "The spread of bare infinitival complements in Present-Day English", by Marcus Callies